# Apple: Read-only HFS+ on Windows 10 with boot camp driver

Tags: macos, mac, multi-boot, boot-camp, hfs+

I've been searching around on the internet for a while trying to answer this question, but I can't get a clear answer for it.

Background info: I'm running El Capitan with a Windows 10 partition on my MBP that I created through Boot Camp. When I ran the boot camp assistant, I made sure the "Download latest support software from apple" box was checked. After that my computer rebooted and I installed Windows onto the newly created partition from a USB drive. I then booted into Windows, where an Installer for the Boot Camp Windows Software popped up. I installed it.

I've read on the internet that the Boot Camp Support Software allows read-only access to the Macintosh HFS+ partition, BUT windows does not recognize the partition, I can't even read from it. Why is this? Is what I read wrong? Or is there a different thing I need to install that's not the software apple put on my Windows Install USB? Or is this feature simply not supported in Windows 10?

I can't figure out why this drive is not accessible to me even though a bunch of places on the internet say that support is included in the Boot Camp Support Software, which I'm fairly sure I installed

EDIT: I realize that there are other third party options to get both read and write support for HFS+, but I am specifically looking for an option built in by Apple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved it!

This literally took hours out of my day, but I now know what the problem was. It turned out that the drivers actually were installed. by verified this checking for the presence of the following files:

```
C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\AppleHFS.sys
C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\AppleMNT.sys
```

The reason that the drive was unreadable is because they **were encrypted with FileVault**. I disabled FileVault in OS X, and when I booted into Windows again, the partition was mounted.

There might be a way to use FileVault and Boot Camp together, I'm not sure. I read in a few places, however, that if you enable FileVault *after* installing Windows with Boot Camp, you can have your drive encrypted and accessible from windows. *(This is just a hunch however, I'll have to look into it more)*

Answer (score 1):

We hade the same problem at our place and FileVault was deactivated.

To be able to access your HFS+ Partition from Windows do the following:

1) Boot in MacOS

2) Open terminal

3) sudo su

4) diskutil corestorage list

5) find the UUID of your macintosh logical volume partition (usually the last, 
with the size of your MacOS partition)

6) diskutil corestorage revert UUID

7) this will revert the partition to standard partition (not logical volume) it's a quick operation, instantly reverted my 512GB SSD with no data loss

Reboot in windows, and now enjoy YOUR data